# Header HTML has 100% height with wkhtmltopdf 0.12

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, pdfkit

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12 with wicked_pdf or pdfkit and the header takes almost 100% of the page height.

It creates these problems :

- Pages are almost empty
- There are many more pages than it should

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this by adding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of the header HTML file.

Somewhat capricious, I know...